# question about 2-local subgroup in finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Thanks for any comment or answer.

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. Then we call $H$ is a $p$-local subgroup of $G$ if $H=N_G(P)$ for some $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$. 
My question is: Is it possible to characterize or have a theorem about group $G$ such that $G$ is not equal to union of all 2-local subgroups, i.e. $G\neq \cup N_G(P)$ where indexed over all 2-subgroup $P$ of $G$. It is not hard to see $S_3,D_{10}$ are simple example for such groups.

Comment: This seems very ambitious

Comment: You are basically asking to classify finite groups in which there is a non-identity element normalizing no non-identity $2$-subgroup.

Comment: Frobenius groups with kernels of odd order all have this property ( which is why you have the examples $S_{3}$ and $D_{10}$).

Comment: @Geoff, Yes, I want to know more about the structure of these class of groups.

Comment: As you pointed out, it seems that these groups or some of their subgroups have close relation with Frobenius groups.

Comment: Finite groups with a (proper) strongly embedded subgroup also have this property.

Comment: It might help to have some examples of groups outside this class, which have no normal 2-subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit too long for a comment.... And I write in haste, so all of the details need to be checked....

It might be possible to prove some kind of reduction theorem here: if you look at $F^*(G)$, then you can assume that it has no normal $2$-group (or $G$ itself is 2-local and you're done).

So now consider $F(G)$, and let $S$ be a Sylow $t$-subgroup of $F(G)$ for some odd prime $t$. You can look at the quotient $G/C_G(S)$; if this quotient satisfies the criterion (it's a union of 2-locals), then the same is true of $G$. So this becomes a question about a group $L$ such that $F^*(L)$ is a $t$-group. We're really thinking about automorphisms of $p$-groups here...

On the other hand, consider the layer $E(G)$, and suppose that $T=T_1\circ \cdots T_k$ is a central product of isomorphic quasisimples that is normal in $G$. Again you look at the quotient of $G/C_G(T)$ -- if it satisfies the criterion, then the same is true of $G$. So this becomes a question about a group $M$ such that $F^*(M)$ is a direct product of isomorphic quasisimples. This is really a question about quasisimples, and CFSG might yield an answer.

The final part of the reduction would require that you show that if $G$ satisfies the criterion, then a quotient of one of the two types just described must satisfy the criterion. I think this follows because, by Bender's Theorem, the intersection of all the centralizers is just $Z(F^*(G))$ and, since we're assuming $F^*(G)$ has no normal $2$-groups, $Z(F^*(G))$ has odd order. Now if $G$ satisfies the criterion, then any quotients by groups of odd order clearly satisfy the criterion, and this can be used to complete the reduction...

Comment: I am not sure that I agree with your last statement. If $G$ has the property, then it is not necessarily the case that $G/O_{2^{\prime}}(G)$ has the property. It could be that every element which normalizes no non-identity $2$-subgroup lies in $O_{2^{\prime}}(G)$- consider a Frobenius group with kernel of odd order and complement of even order.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, Yes, that's a good point, thanks for pointing that out. The situation you describe is rather specific though, so could be studied as a case unto itself... I must admit that I'm not entirely convinced that the reduction described in the final paragraph can be carried out, even allowing for the case that you describe, I'd need to think about it some more...